# How to import sass using tilde prefix with webpack, sass-loader and dart sass

Tags: webpack, sass, sass-loader

This is my repo
https://github.com/inspiraller/eg-webpack4-dartsass-import

I could remove the tilde and it would work, but I'm transitioning a large repo with lots of existing of **~node_modules**
so just want to update webpack to support the existing tilde to refer to the root.

For quick reference - These are the webpack sass-loader rules I've already tried and don't work:

```
          {
            loader: 'sass-loader',
            options: {
              sourceMap: isDevelopment,
              // https://www.npmjs.com/package/sass-loader
              // Prefer `dart-sass`
              implementation: sass,
              sassOptions: {
                fiber: false, // not compatibile with node 16+
              },
              sassOptions: (loaderContext) => {
                console.log('loaderCointext = ', loaderContext) // not even printing any output (suspect because error is breaking)
              },
              includePaths: ["~"], // tried this doesn't work
              webpackImporter: true // just in case - tilde won't work ? - https://webpack.js.org/loaders/sass-loader/ webpackImporter
            }
          }
```

Answer (score 1):

ok I think I've fixed the errors with this solution:

```js
module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    // need * for scss...
    extensions: ['*', '.jsx', '.js'],
    alias: { // fix broken sass
      '~node_modules': path.resolve(__dirname, 'node_modules')
    }
  }
  //, other stuff ...
}
```

But I'm not sure the css is applied because it does not get picked up in the sassOptions callback method:

```
sassOptions: loaderContext => {
                const {resourcePath} = loaderContext
                if (resourcePath.indexOf('node_modules') !== -1) {
                  console.log({resourcePath})
                }
```