# Tilde imports with the dart sass CLI

Tags: sass, node-sass, dart-sass

I'm upgrading an old system with many of these:

```scss
@import "~bootstrap/scss/mixins";
```

That fails when compiling with the dart-sass CLI.

I used to use node-sass, and packages like `node-sass-tilde-importer` and `node-sass-package-importer` to help with that syntax. They don't seem to work for dart-sass.

Given that I'm now using the [dart sass](https://github.com/sass/dart-sass) CLI, how do I deal with this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The solution is simple, but unfortunately **does not support the tilde syntax**.

The scss file should have this:

```scss
@import "foo/bar";            // <--- must remove tilde
```

And the cli syntax is:

```bash
sass --load-path=path/to/node_modules SomeFile.scss SomeFile.css
```

For completeness, the obvious other solution is:

```scss
@import "../../../node_modules/foo/bar";
```

Answer (score 1):

Dart Sass CLI? I think there is no way to import like this in Dart Sass. You have to do it manually.

But there is a Sass migrator to fix legacy sass code, give it a try :

https://sass-lang.com/documentation/cli/migrator

If you are using it with module bundlers, this might help:

[How to import sass using tilde prefix with webpack, sass-loader and dart sass](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69252313/how-to-import-sass-using-tilde-prefix-with-webpack-sass-loader-and-dart-sass)

Comment: Thanks. I was under the impression that I could do something like that using `--load-path`? With node sass it was possible with `--importer`, and I thought the two are the same in functionality?